# WSL1804 (universe enabled): Can't install p7zip-full

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, 7zip

I need to use `7z` on wsl-ub1804, so I try to install it through `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full` but it failed. 
I've check [ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/p7zip-full) so I'm sure that it's there.

I've check [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository), and my universe repo is enabled

here is my console log if needed.

What is problem and how could I fix it?

```
longwsl@DESKTOP-3NGNNKU:~$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package p7zip-full is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'p7zip-full' has no installation candidate
longwsl@DESKTOP-3NGNNKU:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
longwsl@DESKTOP-3NGNNKU:~$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package p7zip-full is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'p7zip-full' has no installation candidate
longwsl@DESKTOP-3NGNNKU:~$
```

Comment: I've just `sudo apt-get update` and it works now, thanks, can you reply in answer so I could mark it as `Answer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `sudo apt-get update` OR `sudo apt update`

After you make any change to your sources (like adding the Universe repository), you must update apt's database of available packages.